# Understanding the largest closed under homeomorphism class of complete metric spaces

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness, complete-spaces

It is well known that completeness is [not](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/134400/preservation-of-completeness-under-homeomorphism) a property maintained by homeomorphism ($\cong$) between metric spaces.

Let $\mathcal{C}$ denote the class of all complete metric spaces satisfying that for all $X\in\mathcal{C}$ and $Y$ metric space, if $X \cong Y$ then $Y$ is also complete. Class $\mathcal{C}$ is the largest class of complete metric spaces that is closed under homeomorphism.

Let $\mathcal{C_0}$ denote the class of all compact metric spaces. We [know](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/627667/every-compact-metric-space-is-complete) that $\mathcal{C_0}\subseteq \mathcal{C}$.

> Is it the case that $\mathcal{C_0}=\mathcal{C}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as any non-compact metric space has an equivalent (same topology yielding) metric that is *not* complete. E.g cf. [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/a/22031) for ideas.