# Example of Homeomorphism Between Complete and Incomplete Metric Spaces

Tags: metric-spaces

Is it possible to have a homeomorphism between a complete metric space and an incomplete one? If so, what examples can be given?

Comment: As a side note, if there is a homeomorphism to a complete metric space, then there exists a metric to the other set as well that makes it a complete metric space. Being homeomorphic to a complete metric space is called "Completely metrizable".

Comment: [Example of Homeomorphism Between Complete and Incomplete Metric Spaces](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/296502/example-of-homeomorphism-between-complete-and-incomplete-metric-spaces),
[preservation of completeness under homeomorphism](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/134400/preservation-of-completeness-under-homeomorphism),
[Is Completeness intrinsic to a space?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114799/is-completeness-intrinsic-to-a-space)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A simple example is the homeomorphism
$$(0, 1) \longrightarrow \Bbb R,$$
$$x \mapsto \tan( \pi(x - \tfrac{1}{2})).$$
Here we give both $(0,1)$ and $\Bbb R$ the usual Euclidean metric. $\Bbb R$ is of course complete, but $(0,1)$ is not complete since the Cauchy sequence $\{1/n\} \subset (0,1)$ doesn't converge in $(0,1)$.

Answer (score 3):

Consider $X=\mathbb R$ and $Y=(-1,1)$ with the standard metric.
Then
$f(x)=\frac{x}{|x|+1}$ is a homeomorphism $X\to Y$.

Comment: +1 Do you mean by Standard metric; Euclidean metric?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, possible.

The easiest is $\Bbb R\to (0,1)$ with the usual metrics. $\Bbb R$ is complete, though in some limit sense it still misses its endpoints, which are effectively missing in $(0,1)$.