# $X \cong Y$, $X$ complete $\implies Y$ complete?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

- Let $\cong$ denote the homeomorphic notation.
- > Let $X,Y$ be metric spaces, and let $X \cong Y$. If $X$ is a complete metric space does it imply $Y$ is also complete.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be (temporarily) closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/xQWVb) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: [Example of Homeomorphism Between Complete and Incomplete Metric Spaces](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/296502/example-of-homeomorphism-between-complete-and-incomplete-metric-spaces), 
[preservation of completeness under homeomorphism](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/134400/preservation-of-completeness-under-homeomorphism), 
[Is Completeness intrinsic to a space?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114799/is-completeness-intrinsic-to-a-space)

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** $(0,1)$ in the standard metric is incomplete, and $\Bbb R$ is complete.